# Magento 2 - PHPUnit skip classes that are extended by \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, phpunit

Today is my first day using PHPUnit, I've installed phpunit6.1, php7.1 and trying to write simple `assertEquals` test. When I extend my test class with `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` - everything works nice, but I can't create an object because `\Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager` requires `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` object, not `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`. When I extend my class with `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` - phpunit just skip this test.

How to fix that?

**Magento version**: 2.1.4

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Magento testing framework, you have to stick with PHPUnit 5.x where the old class names are still used.

The core tests even run on PHPUnit 4.1 (see `composer.json`), but in my experience, you can create your own tests in PHPUnit 5.